# Complex Unix Find Command

Tags: unix, find

I am trying extract 2 different peices of information into 2 separate files using a single "find" command.  Essentially, I am trying to find all files in a directory that are hardlinks and regular files with no hardlinks.

I know I can run  2 find commnands 1 using find . -links 1 > file and find . ! -links 1 > file2.
I wanted to combine this to a single find but have not been successful.  Here is the command that I am starting with:

```
find . -type f \( \( -links 1 -exec echo {} >> /tmp/foo1 \; \) \) -o \( \( ! -links 1 -exec echo {} >> /tmp/foo2 \; \) \)
```

This command seems to ignore the first expression. 
The first expression looks for all files with one link.  The second expression looks for all files with any links not equal to 1.  I use exec to attempt to create a file.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you need `>>` (append redirection) for this. It can also frustrate your testing, if you don't look "down" in the file to see what new has been appended. If you just want to echo the filename, why use `exec echo`. just `-print` or `-print0` might simplify your problem. Good luck.

Comment: My goal is to get a list of files with the first expression into one file and a list of all files with hard links into another file.  Note the "-links 1" and the second expression "! -links 1".  it is true that I don't necessarily need to redirect the outout but then I would have to exec another script and possibly stat each file (could be millions).  My work around is to use two find commands, but I am not giving up yet to do it in one.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: yes, I understood your `links 1` and `! links 1` and the desire to do one scan for multiple purposes. Couldn't you just run 1 basic scan with an `-ls` included (or if your find supports a printf with  `stat` like ability) and then parse the output based on the first char of the permissions mask that is output (i.e. 'l', 'd', -s')? Also, I don't know why you have 2 sets of `\( \(` around each 1/2. Is that necessary? ---- As `find` is not easy to debug, I'm just looking to eliminate any unnecessary syntax that may be not working as you expect. Same with the `exec echo`. Good luck!

Comment: I was unable to get file redirection to work with each expression so what I did was use exec to add flag to the echo statement to get 2 columns and I will parse that file after the find completes:

    <pre>
find . -type f \( ! -links 1 -exec echo "H " {} \; \) -o \( -links 1 -exec echo "F " {} \;  \) > /tmp/masterlist
</pre>

Comment: So does that give you the result you need? If so, post it as an answer (with sample inputs (ls -l ... 5 files or so) AND the resulting output. Good luck.